# How to pull out pairs of data from a list inside a dataframe (with tidyverse)

Tags: r, json, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a json output (from topydo) which has (after some manipulation) a column called tags where the tags (if they are present) are pairs of data in a list.  Usually they will be a due date "due",  sometimes a repeat date "rec", and sometimes both.   Reproducible example below which produces a dataframe with a 'tags' column containing lists the lists of due/rec pairs.

I want to pull these lists apart (akin to `pivot_wider` or `spread`) but for the elements in the list, so I want to turn this list item:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]  [,2]        
[1,] "rec" "+6m"       
[2,] "due" "2020-02-02"
```

into two columns - rec and due.

This is what the 'tags' column looks like:

```
> todo.df$tags
[[1]]
     [,1]  [,2]        
[1,] "rec" "+6m"       
[2,] "due" "2020-02-02"

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
     [,1]  [,2]        
[1,] "due" "2020-03-01"
[2,] "rec" "+1y"       

[[4]]
     [,1]  [,2]        
[1,] "due" "2020-05-01"
```

I have tried a variety of the `unnest` functions but can't work out how to pull the due dates and the rec date into their own columns.

Any help appreciated.

---

Reproducible example:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
todo.df <- "[{\"contexts\": [], \"priority\": null, \"projects\": [], \"source\": \"organise website review.  rec:+6m due:2020-02-02\", \"tags\": [[\"rec\", \"+6m\"], [\"due\", \"2020-02-02\"]], \"text\": \"organise website review.\"}, {\"contexts\": [\"smtl\", \"jim\"], \"priority\": \"B\", \"projects\": [], \"source\": \"(B) create wiki page on installing packages @jim @smtl\", \"tags\": [], \"text\": \"create wiki page on installing packages @jim @smtl\"}, {\"contexts\": [\"smtl\", \"jim\"], \"priority\": null, \"projects\": [], \"source\": \"Joomla mobile interface @smtl @jim due:2020-03-01 rec:+1y\", \"tags\": [[\"due\", \"2020-03-01\"], [\"rec\", \"+1y\"]], \"text\": \"Joomla mobile interface @smtl @jim\"}, {\"contexts\": [\"smtl\", \"jim\"], \"priority\": null, \"projects\": [], \"source\": \"review wiki documents @smtl @jim due:2020-05-01\", \"tags\": [[\"due\", \"2020-05-01\"]], \"text\": \"review wiki documents @smtl @jim\"}]" %>% 
  fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select (priority, contexts, projects, tags, text)
```

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/8467042/a-suliman for fixing the example - I realised I'd left the library calls out last night driving home!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map_if` to create a clean `data.frame` if the `tags` has 1+ rows then later you can do a normal `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(map)
library(tidyr)
todo.df %>% 
  mutate(tags_cln = map_if(tags, 
                           .p = ~nrow(data.frame(.x))>=1, 
                           .f = ~data.frame(.x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
                                   #Incase we have two or more in due and/or rec, for a simple demo uncomment the following 
                                   #e.g data.frame(todo.df$tags[[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
                                   group_by(X1) %>% 
                                   mutate(id_r=row_number()) %>% 
                                   spread(X1, X2) %>% 
                                   select(-id_r), 
                           .else = ~data.frame(due=NA_character_, rec=NA_character_))) %>% 
  unnest(tags_cln)


# A tibble: 4 x 7
  priority contexts  projects   tags              text                                               due        rec  
  <chr>    <list>    <list>     <list>            <chr>                                              <chr>      <chr>
1 NA       <chr [0]> <list [0]> <chr[,2] [2 × 2]> organise website review.                           2020-02-02 +6m  
2 B        <chr [2]> <list [0]> <list [0]>        create wiki page on installing packages @jim @smtl NA         NA   
3 NA       <chr [2]> <list [0]> <chr[,2] [2 × 2]> Joomla mobile interface @smtl @jim                 2020-03-01 +1y  
4 NA       <chr [2]> <list [0]> <chr[,2] [1 × 2]> review wiki documents @smtl @jim                   2020-05-01 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit messy but working solution:

```
todo.df$due <- NA
todo.df$rec <- NA
for (line in 1:nrow(todo.df)) {
  found_tags <- todo.df[line, "tags"][[1]][[1]]
  if (length(found_tags) > 0) {
    for (tag_line in 1:nrow(found_tags)) {
      todo.df[line, found_tags[tag_line, 1]] <- found_tags[tag_line, 2]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I've adopted the code from @A.Suliman I can confirm that this code also works for me.  Thank you.